# c# entity framework max id and many rows

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, group-by, max

The table contains many millions of records. I need to get all the latest entries less than the current time without duplicates.

The data looks like this:

```
id|parentId|alias|value|datepoint
181565 |1|frequency6   |0    |2017-07-21 16:45:22.763
181566 |1|tag          |1    |2017-07-21 16:45:22.763
181567 |1|ord          |45688|2017-07-21 16:45:22.763
181568 |1|target_status|-1   |2017-07-21 16:45:22.763
1032193|1|frequency6   |0    |2017-07-21 17:15:04.833
1032194|1|tag          |1    |2017-07-21 17:15:04.833
1032195|1|ord          |45688|2017-07-21 17:15:04.833
1032196|1|target_status|-1   |2017-07-21 17:15:04.833
873321 |2|frequency6   |0    |2017-07-21 17:14:00.443
873322 |2|tag          |1    |2017-07-21 17:14:00.443
873323 |2|ord          |5726 |2017-07-21 17:14:00.443
873324 |2|target_status|-1   |2017-07-21 17:14:00.443
22693  |2|frequency6   |0    |2017-07-21 16:44:13.290
22694  |2|tag          |1    |2017-07-21 16:44:13.290
22695  |2|ord          |5726 |2017-07-21 16:44:13.290
22696  |2|target_status|-1   |2017-07-21 16:44:13.290
75625  |3|frequency6   |0    |2017-07-21 16:44:31.037
```

Since id is autoincremented, the query to the database looks like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id), parentId, alias FROM [Raiko].[dbo].[DataDigitalArchives] WHERE alias = 'frequency6' GROUP BY parentId, alias
```

In the application, I use Entity Framework. And the query to the database looks like this:

```
var goupF6 = diContext.Items.Where(f => f.alias == "frequency6" && f.datepoint <= DateTime.Now).GroupBy(f => new { f.parentId, f.alias }).ToList();
```

But I get a grouped collection of all my entries from the database. 
Tell me, please, how to get only the necessary records?

**edit** 
I only need 0 elements from List>

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**
I did not think of anything better than using the stored procedure.

Comment: The query and LINQ both seem fine. You shouldn't be getting all records. Double check.

Comment: Hope by EF you don't have in mind EF Core? Also note that the LINQ query is not equivalent of the SQL query.

Comment: Ivan, EF - Entity Framework.

Comment: Racil, I get it - List<IGroupig<a,myObject>>. And each element contains all the entries grouped.

Comment: Racil, added screenshots.

Comment: I chaged my code: var groupF6 = diContext.Items.Where(f => f.alias == "frequency6" && f.datepoint <= DateTime.Now).GroupBy(f => new { f.parentId, f.alias }).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.id).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();     But this very slow.

Comment: What you wrote in your last comment (btw, you should update your question rather than commenting) is basically the EF solution. You could try grouping only by `parentId` (since `alias` according to the `where` is one and the same anyway), but in general you cannot speed it up. Note that the SQL query you've shown is **not equivalent** because it doesn't return the whole record, but `Max(id)` only.